# How do I rearrange columns in gtsummary or flextable?

Tags: r, flextable, gtsummary

In reference to this answer [confidence intervals] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66891473/13734451),
how can rearrange the columns in gtsummary or flextable? There is a way to do this using **gt package** (as below) but that wont knit to Ms Word. Any leads?

```
final_tbl %>% as_gt() %>%
  cols_move(
    columns = vars(Male_ci),
    after = vars(stat_1)
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of moving a column of a gtsummary object. This script moves the `p.value` column to after the `label` column

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> '1.4.0'

# build table
tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_p() 

# move p.value column
tbl %>%
  modify_table_body(~.x %>% dplyr::relocate(p.value, .after = label))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you greatly @Daniel. That perfectly solved my problem