# Rearrange rows or columns in R flextable

Tags: r, flextable

Once I have created a flextable in R, how do I rearrange rows or columns?

This is very similar to the question "[How do I rearrange columns in gtsummary or flextable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893532/how-do-i-rearrange-columns-in-gtsummary-or-flextable)". However, the only answer there gave how to solve the problem in gtsummary, but I want to solve it using flextable only. Here is an example:

```
library(flextable)

ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
ft
```

Result:

[image]

While working with the ft object, how do I do the following:

- Move hp to the second column (that is, in between mpg and cyl)?
- Move the third row (mpg = 22.8) to become the first row?
- Sort the results by wt?

Comment: you cant, this is not a feature, once the flextable exists, it is static. You can do it prior to the flextable creation

Comment: Thanks. Could you please make that an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score -2):

```
mtcars %>%
head() %>%
arrange(wt) %>%
flextable(col_keys = c("mpg", "hp", "cyl", "disp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", 
"am", "gear", "carb"))
```

Comment: The question asks how to do the arrangements after creating the flextable, not before. According to the comment by the package developer to the original question, it seems that it is not possible.