# How to use gtsummary::tbl_svysummary() to display confidence intervals for levels of a factor variable?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am using survey data from the National Electronic Injury Surveillance System (https://www.cpsc.gov/Research--Statistics/NEISS-Injury-Data) to research trends in consumer product injuries.

Using gtsummary and tbl_svysummary(), my goal is to create a descriptive table of summary measures of injuries.  Since this is survey data, I want to display the 95% confidence interval associated with each summary measure.

This previous post provides a solution to generating confidence intervals for two level factor variables ([Using (gtsummary) tbl_svysummaary function to display confidence intervals for survey.design object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814238/using-gtsummary-tbl-svysummaary-function-to-display-confidence-intervals-for-s)), however, I am looking for a solution to produce confidence intervals for factor variables with >=2 levels.

I am borrowing a reproducible example from the previous post:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(survey)

svy_trial <-
  svydesign(~1, data = trial %>% select(trt, response, death), weights = ~1) 

ci <- function(variable, by, data, ...) {
  svyby(as.formula( paste0( "~" , variable)) , by = as.formula( paste0( "~" , by)), data, svyciprop, vartype="ci") %>%
    tibble::as_tibble() %>%
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(ci_l, ci_u), ~style_number(., scale = 100) %>% paste0("%")) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(ci = stringr::str_glue("{ci_l}, {ci_u}")) %>%
    dplyr::select(all_of(c(by, "ci"))) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = all_of(by), values_from = ci) %>%
    set_names(paste0("add_stat_", seq_len(ncol(.))))
}

ci("response", "trt", svy_trial)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   add_stat_1 add_stat_2
#>   <glue>     <glue>    
#> 1 21%, 40%   25%, 44%  

svy_trial %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = "trt", missing = "no") %>%
  add_stat(everything() ~ "ci") %>%
  modify_table_body(
    dplyr::relocate, add_stat_1, .after = stat_1
  ) %>%
  modify_header(starts_with("add_stat_") ~ "**95% CI**") %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA)
```

Table screenshot from previous post [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MIiE.png)

In the above example, the factor variables have two levels and summary data from 1 level is shown.

1. How can I tweak the above approach so that both levels of factor variables are displayed with their respective confidence intervals?
2. How can this solution be generalized to factor variables with >2 levels (e.g., an age variable binned as follows: <18 years, 18-25 years, 26-50 years, etc)?
3. Lastly, how could this desired solution also accommodate generating confidence intervals for continuous variables in the same column as the confidence intervals for factor variables?

Here is an example of the table I am trying to produce:
Screenshot of desired table output[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A43A.jpg)

Apologies if this request for help doesn't follow good stack overflow etiquette (I'm fairly new to this community) and your time and assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a prepared example for factors with >=2 levels, but not with a `by=` variable (although the approach is similar). FYI, we have an open issue to support survey objects more thoroughly with a new function `add_ci.tbl_svysummary()` that will calculate CIs for both categorical and continuous variables. You can click the "subscribe" link here to be alerted when this feature is implemented https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/965

In the meantime, here is a code example:

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

svy <- survey::svydesign(~1, data = as.data.frame(Titanic), weights = ~Freq) 

# put the CI in a tibble with the variable name
# first create a data frame with each variable and it's values
df_result <- 
  tibble(variable = c("Class", "Sex", "Age", "Survived")) %>%
  # get the levels of each variable in a new column
  # adding them as a list to allow for different variable classes
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    # level to be used to construct call
    level = unique(svy$variables[[variable]]) %>% as.list() %>% list(),
    # character version to be merged into table
    label = unique(svy$variables[[variable]]) %>% as.character() %>% as.list() %>% list()
  ) %>%
  unnest(c(level, label)) %>%
  mutate(
    label = unlist(label)
  )

# construct call to svyciprop
df_result$svyciprop <-
  map2(
    df_result$variable, df_result$label,
    function(variable, level) rlang::inject(survey::svyciprop(~I(!!rlang::sym(variable) == !!level), svy))
  )


# round/format the 95% CI
df_result <-
  df_result %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    ci = 
      svyciprop %>%
      attr("ci") %>%
      style_sigfig(scale = 100) %>%
      paste0("%", collapse = ", ")
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  # keep variables needed in tbl
  select(variable, label, ci)


# construct gtsummary table with CI
tbl <- 
  svy %>%
  tbl_svysummary() %>%
  # merge in CI
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      left_join(
        df_result, 
        by = c("variable", "label")
      )
  ) %>%
  # add a header
  modify_header(ci = "**95% CI**")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, this example code was helpful.  Re: upcoming gtsummary function add_ci.tbl_svysummary(), if it is not too late I'd like to suggest that this function include the option of generating confidence intervals of the point estimates (i.e., in addition to the ability of generating CI for proportions).  Your work on gtsummary is much appreciated!

Comment: FYI the add_ci.tbl_svysummary() function was added in gtsummary v1.7.0